# Receiving "Exception HResult 0x800540402" when trying to create a new project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I can create one or two types of projects but the majoriry give the "Exception HResult 0x800540402" error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be an extension problem!

In my case it was "Incredibuild" I had disabled it some time ago maybe 3 months. Apparently one of the recent updates created a situation where this was not allowed. I reenabled it and all was well.